# JavaScript XML Search - Display message if no match is found

Tags: javascript, xml, search, loops, match

I have a html file that contains a input box to enter a first name. On click this runs through a JavaScript function that loads an XML file to see if there are any matches. If there are matches, they are to be displayed in a table with the matching contact information. I can do this fine.

But I am required to also show an alert if there is no match. That is "If the Contact Does not Exist".

Now, the for loop in my code messes innerHTML up, which is fair enough, it loops that particular code over and over again and so any code inside is parsed. This is why the innerHTML is outside the loop.

But I want to display a message before the table is called if no contact exists.

It is probably something very simple, but it has evaded me all day, again.

Heres my code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
} 
function searchXML()
{
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("Contact.xml");
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
    input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    size = input.length;
    divText =  "<table border=1><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Street</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Postcode</th></tr>";
    if (input == null || input == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Please enter a character or name!";
        return false;
    }
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        startString = firstname.substring(0,size);
        if (startString.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase())
        {
            firstname=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("firstname")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            lastname=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lastname")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            phone=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("phone")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            street=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("street")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            city=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            state=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("state")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            postcode=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("postcode")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            divText = divText + "<tr><td>" + firstname + "</td><td>" + lastname + "</td><td>" + phone + "</td><td>" + street + "</td><td>" + city + "</td><td>" + state + "</td><td>" + postcode + "</td></tr>";
            }
    }
    //insert does not exist code here
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "<h2>The contact does not exist.</h2>";
    return false;
    //end insert
    divText =  "<h1>The contact details are:</h1><br />" + divText + "</table>";
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= divText;
}
</script>
```

My html body:

```
<body>
First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="input">
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="searchXML()">
<br />
<br />
<div id="results">
</div>
</body>
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: can you creat js fiddle for this

Comment: The Javascript wont fire. I think its due to not being on a server. I had the same problem firing locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my problem. The problem was that divText with table data was being displayed even if there was no contact.

There is an if else statement inside the for loop. See below for full working code.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
    xhttp.send();
    return xhttp.responseXML;
} 
function searchXML()
{
    xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("Contact.xml");
    x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("firstname");
    input = document.getElementById("input").value;
    size = input.length;
    if (input == null || input == "")
    {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= "Please enter a character or name!";
        return false;
    }
    for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        startString = firstname.substring(0,size);
        if (startString.toLowerCase() == input.toLowerCase())
        {
            firstname=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("firstname")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            lastname=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("lastname")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            phone=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("phone")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            street=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("street")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            city=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("city")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            state=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("state")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            postcode=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("postcode")[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            divText = "<h1>The contact details are:</h1><br /><table border=1><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Street</th><th>City</th><th>State</th><th>Postcode</th></tr>" + "<tr><td>" + firstname + "</td><td>" + lastname + "</td><td>" + phone + "</td><td>" + street + "</td><td>" + city + "</td><td>" + state + "</td><td>" + postcode + "</td></tr>" + "</table>";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            divText = "<h2>The contact does not exist.</h2>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML= divText;
}
</script>
```

I hope this can help someone else out